# Magento 2 Thumbnails missing in store view (language)

Tags: magento2, product-images, magento2.3.1, thumbnail

I'm using Magento 2.3.1. We have 3 store views for multi language. One store view (German language) doesn't display category thumbnails correctly. The other do not have any problems. We tried reindexing, rebuild static content, clear cache. On the product pages the images are OK, the problem is only on the category pages. Any ideas?

Comment: can you be more specific. Is there any errors in the console? Are you getting 404 on the images or it's loading the placeholder instead of the images. How exactly the images are missing.

Comment: We do not have any console errors because (as you said) the placeholders are displayed. So all store views have the correct images except this one. The detail pages have no problems.

Comment: did you resolve the case? i have same probleme

Comment: No, we did not. Still searching for a solution..

Answer (score 1):

did you resolve the case? I have exactly the same problem, product thumbnail images not shown on category pages. 
No error on console.

Magento 2.3.1 and using SM Market theme,
If you already resolved the case please inform 
regards

Comment: No, we have not fixed it yet :-( Still hoping for someone to answer this..

Comment: @AntondeG I am also looking the solution if anyone found kindly share here

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and I found what is happening at least in my case. I noticed that for products with the issue, the image don't has roles applied.

[image]

Just apply roles:

[image]

Of course It is a manual task, but I thing a script could be created to update the database (insert values into catalog_product_entity_varchar)

Example of data to be inserted:
[image]